# Maven/Eclipse: generated bytecode differs (NoSuchMethodError)

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

This is the scenario (pseudo code):

```
class X

class Y extends X

class A
  public void methodA(X x){}

class B extends A

class Main
  main() {
    new B().methodA(new Y());
  }
```

When running from within Eclipse everything is fine. When building with maven, I will get a NoSuchMethodError at runtime.
I had a look at the bytecode.

The Eclipse compiler generated bytecode looks like this:

```
invokevirtual B.methodA(X)
```

The maven compiler generated bytecode looks like this:

```
invokevirtual B.methodA(Y)
```

Which leads to the `NoSuchMethodError` saying that `B` has no method "`methodA`" that takes the argument type `Y` (method signature differs by paramter type).

Do you have any ideas what can be wrong? I have checked that both environments use the same value for both source/target which is set to 1.6

Anything else to check?

Thanks!

Comment: The difference might be that be default eclipse uses its own compiler while maven uses the JAVA_HOME JDK compiler ... but without any further information its hard to figure out what's wrong here...

Comment: FIXED: The solution was to use `mvn clean -Pprofilename`. I did not provide the profile to clean.

Comment: @erdal.karaca I don't think that your comment could help someone with your same problem. Can you make an anserw where you explain us like you solved your trouble

Comment: Why do you need a profile to clean things. Does not make sense.

Comment: (I am no maven expert, so answering from a newbie's POV) In my case, the parent defined modules which were assigned to a profile. When doing a `mvn clean` (from the parent pom) the module artifacts (for example, class files) were not deleted by default. When providing the profile name of the module the artifacts were cleared/deleted as expected.